# Implements Generics in C#

Tags: c#, generics, collections

I am a student and want to implement generic in my test project. Below is my code

```
class clsCallService
{
    public void CallServiceMethod(string serviceName)
    {
        if (serviceName == "WEB")
            Web_Service.AddData("4G", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, "test");
        else if (serviceName == "VOICE")
            Voice_Service.AddData("4G", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, "test");
        else if (serviceName == "VIDEO")
            Video_Service.AddData("4G", DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, "test");
    }
}       

class Web_Service
{
    public static void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    { 
        //Call DAL method
    }
}

class Voice_Service
{
    public static void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    {
        //Call DAL method
    }
}

class Video_Service
{
    public static void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    {
        //Call DAL method
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a generic class. In this class, there should be a generic method which has a generic parameter. So, I wouldn't need to write IF Condition like above. I just need to pass a object of any class and base of type, method will be called. I am trying to write some code but not able to do.

```
public class testGenericClass<T> where T : Web_Service, new()
{
    public void CallServiceMethod(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    {
        T.AddData(technology, SDate, EDate, someVariable);
    }
}
```

Please suggest.

---

Updated after got some helpful replies --

Updated code

```
public class createGenericClass<T> where T : IWebService,IVoiceService
{
    public void CallDoSomeThing(T t, int x, int y)
    {
        t.DoSomeThing(x, y);
    }

    public void CallDoSomeThingElse(T t, int a, float b)
    {
        t.DoSomeThingElse(a, b);
    }

}

public interface IWebService
{
    void DoSomeThing(int x, int y);        
}

public interface IVoiceService
{
    void DoSomeThingElse(int a, float b);
}

public class Web_Service : IWebService
{
    public void DoSomeThing(int x, int y)
    { }    
}    

public class Voice_Service : IVoiceService
{
    public void DoSomeThingElse(int a, float b)
    { }
}
```

Now, I have two different interfaces i.e. Web and Voice. Both have different functions. I have implemented it successfully but I am not able to call my method. I don't know how to call. Below Code (Just trying to create a new instance.)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        createGenericClass<IWebService> obj = new createGenericClass<IWebService>();

    }
}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Without knowing too much about what you are trying to achieve, it looks like you really want to use an interface, not Generics.

Comment: I can use interface. Example - I can achieve it by dependency injection.

Comment: See the example by @jdphenix below - it explains it better than I can in comments :)

Comment: Since all methods are exactly the same, you don't need generics at all. Just have them implement the same interface consisting of the `AddData` method.

Comment: @Groo..If I have different methods for different jobs, then I need generics??

Comment: @Mohit: you might need generics if method signatures differ only in the type of one or more of its parameters (i.e. `AddData(SomeType a, string b)` and `AddData(SomeOtherType a, string b)`).

Comment: Adding generics for that simple of a purpose is no good. I support @Groo on simply implementing an interface use that as an abstraction when calling `AddData`.

Comment: @Groo.. I have updated my question. Please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare an interface that all your classes would implement, like

```
interface IService 
{
    void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable); 
}
```

Then each class implements, like:

```
public class Web_Service : IService
{
    public void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable) {
        // do stuff... 
    }
}
// etc...
```

I think it's worth pointing out that if you use an interface like this, you could just accept a parameter of type `IService`, not needing generics at all.

```
public void CallServiceMethod(IService service, string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable) 
{
    service.AddData(technology, SDate, EDate, someVariable); 
}
```

---

If you need something that uses a generic method for some reason, then a generic method could be written, constrained by the interface,

```
public class testGenericClass<T> where T : IService
{
    public void CallServiceMethod(T t, string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    {
        t.AddData(technology, SDate, EDate, someVariable);
    }
}
```

Note that this method requires that the interface method `AddData()` is an instance method, not a static method like you have now.

Comment: Thank you. 
Is it possible without Interface?? Just a question.

Comment: Sure, for example an abstract class or abstract method. That's ultimately the same kind of relationship though. I did think of something else that I'm going to add.

Comment: There is no need for the generic method in this case, it adds no value. They should just share the same interface. If you want, you can also create an abstract class (or a base class with a default implementation) to reuse code, but interface is a contract they need to fulfill.

Comment: @Groo I think we thought the same thing at the same time.

Comment: Thank you all. Actually, I am learning about Generics so I just want to implement it. But, I got your point. Thanks again

Comment: If you want to learn a good use case for generics, implement a data structure. A linked list implementing `IEnumerable<T>` should be straightforward

Comment: Thanks. I will definitely try. If you have better study stuff of Generics , Please post. (except MSDN)

Answer (score 2):

You can't call static functions on generic types so I assume you are trying to call an instance method. You need to instantiate `T` before calling `.AddData(...)`

```
public class testGenericClass<T> where T : Web_Service, new()
{
    public void CallServiceMethod(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    {
        new T().AddData(technology, SDate, EDate, someVariable);
    }
}

class Web_Service
{
    public void AddData(string technology, DateTime SDate, DateTime EDate, String someVariable)
    { 
        //Call DAL method
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It works. But this is not what I wanted. Now, If I call this method, this works only for Web_Service class. Is there any way to call this method for each class i.e. WEB, VOICE, and VIDEO

Comment: Don't worry... there are plenty of us that want to be able to call static methods on interfaces and generics but that's not how C# or CLR works.

Answer (score 0):

When you look at how generics are used in .NET base class library, you will see it's mostly for enumerations and collections (e.g. `List<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`), i.e. data structures which behave the same regardless of the underlying type. Rule of thumb is usually: If you need to check the exact `typeof(T)` inside the generic method, you are probably doing it wrong.

However, one reason why you would check `typeof(T)` in a generic method is in factory methods, i.e. ["service locators"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern), which allow you to get a concrete instance of a certain type. This means you would have a special class which registers concrete implementations of various interfaces at program startup, so that your program can get concrete dependencies without knowing how they were instantiated.

Although pure inversion of control is actually achieved through [constructor dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), the service locator approach gives better design that simply instatiating your dependencies manually (using the `new` keyword). Unit testing is slightly harder, however, because your [dependencies still remain opaque to callers](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/).

Consider something like:

```
public interface IServiceLocator
{
    T GetService<T>();
}

// you use it whenever you would use `new` otherwise,
// to get a concrete instance of some interface, and
// you don't know and don't care where this instance 
// came from:

var webService = ServiceLocator.GetService<IWebService>();
var videoService = ServiceLocator.GetService<IVideoService>();
```

This service locator could be a framework, or you could write it yourself, something as simple as:

```
public class ServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
{
    readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<object>> _typeFactories =
        new Dictionary<Type, Func<object>>();

    public ServiceLocator()
    {
        // register a factory method for each service
        _typeFactories[typeof(IWebService)] = () => new SomeWebService();
        _typeFactories[typeof(IVideoService)] = () => new SomeVideoService();

        // services can also be singletons, if they can be shared
        _typeFactories[typeof(IVoiceService)] = () => VoiceService.Instance;
    }

    public T GetService<T>()
    {
        // get the factory method and invoke it
        // (you will probably want to have some checks here)

        var factory = _typeFactories[typeof(T)];
        return factory();
    }
}
```

In your case, however, it seems all three services share a common interface, so there is no need for generics. You probably wanted to use it like this:

```
IDataService service = ServiceLocator.GetServiceByName("WEB");
service.AddData(...);
```

Which could be implemented as:

```
public interface IDataService 
{
    void AddData(...);
}

public interface IServiceLocator
{
    IDataService GetServiceByName(string name);
}

public class ServiceLocator : IServiceLocator
{
    readonly Dictionary<string, Func<IDataService>> _typeFactories = 
        new Dictionary<string, Func<IDataService>>();

    public ServiceLocator()
    {
        _typeFactories["WEB"] = () => new SomeWebService();
        _typeFactories["VIDEO"] = () => new SomeVideoService();
        _typeFactories["VOICE"] = () => SomeVoiceService.Instance; // singleton            
    }

    public IDataService GetServiceByName(string name)
    {
        var factory = _typeFactories[name];
        return factory();
    }
}
```

So, the rule of thumb is:

1. If you know the interface of the service you want to consume at **compile time**, use a generic factory (i.e. `Locator.GetService<ICanDoSomething>()`).
2. If multiple services share exactly the same interface and you need to differentiate them at runtime, use a factory with a type parameter (i.e. `Locator.GetServiceByName("some-service")`).

Both approaches don't guarantee that this service will exist at run time, but the latter is even more prone to run-time errors (mistyping the service name). And both approaches are inferior to pure DI in terms of weak coupling, while vastly superior over hardcoded dependecies:

```
// bad
public SomeClassConstructor()
{
    _service = new WebService();
}

// better
public SomeClassConstructor(IServiceLocator serviceLocator)
{
    _service = serviceLocator.GetService<IWebService>();
}

// best
public SomeClassConstructor(IWebService webService)
{
    _service = webService;
}
```

I would recommend going for the third approach. Learn about [composition roots](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), you often don't even need a fancy DI framework.